# How to calculate the sum of digits of $2^n$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, exponentiation

How do I find the sum of digits of $2^n$ in general?

Sum of digits of $2^1=2$ is $2$.

Sum of digits of $2^{10}=1024$ is $7$.

I have check there is no obvious pattern or any recurrence that i can find. Any ideas?

** i don't need repeated sums , just single time**

Comment: No, the sum of digits in 2^n

Comment: Why do you think there is an easy way to do this? The base ten representation of a number quite often has no interesting properties (and is fairly arbitrary choice of base.)

Comment: https://oeis.org/A001370

Comment: Although a closed form isn't known yet, it is a rather straightforward exercise to find the sequence of repeated sums of digits of $2^n$ (by repeated sums I mean $2^{11}=2048 \mapsto 14\mapsto 5$)

Comment: @JMoravitz i don't need repeated sums , just single time

Comment: Note from my link: "It is believed $a(n) \sim 9n\log_{10}(2)/2$ but this is an open problem."

Comment: Are you trying to solve [Euler Project 16?](https://projecteuler.net/problem=16)

Comment: @RossMillikan yes, kind of ,some guy coined this in C++ lounge over at SO , i wonder if it can be related to as a general form

Comment: $2^{16}=65536$. It's not clear to me if the question includes disregarding the repetitions of digits nor whether we continue summing to get a single digit number, i.e. $6+5+3\rightarrow14$ and stop there.

Answer (score 6):

Nobody in the world knows how to do this faster than calculating the decimal representation of $2^n$ and adding up all its digits. When $n$ gets big, the challenge is to calculate $2^n$ as fast as possible; Fast Fourier Trasforms are the way to go, but this is a deep subject. Start with Wikipedia's article on [Karatsuba's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm) for a gentle introduction and links to further study.

I won a prize (something grotty, like an internal disk drive mount) 30 years ago, when the ARM was brand new. The problem was to calculate the sum of the digits of the largest known prime, which was then (I think) $2^{216091}-1$. The winner was the program that ran fastest on the ARM-based Archimedes computer.

My winning program used Fast Fourier Transforms. It took three weeks to write, and 4 minutes 33 seconds to run. I remember this because it is the length (and indeed title) of John Cage's minimalist classic *4' 33''*. Also it is 273 seconds, and -273 is absolute zero in degrees Celsius. Some have speculated that this is not a coincidence (I mean John Cage's title, not my program's running time).

Answer (score 3):

$2^{1} = 2$

$2^{2} = 4$

$2^{3} = 8$

$2^{4} = 16 \rightarrow 7$

$2^{5} = 32 \rightarrow 5$

$2^{6} = 64 \rightarrow 10 \rightarrow 1$

Then..

$2^{7} = 128 \rightarrow 11 \rightarrow 2$

$2^{8} = 256 \rightarrow 13 \rightarrow 4$

$2^{9} = 512 \rightarrow 8$

$2^{10} = 1024 \rightarrow 7$

$2^{11} = 2048 \rightarrow 14 \rightarrow 5$

$2^{12} = 4096 \rightarrow 19 \rightarrow 10 \rightarrow 1$

If you keep this up, it seems you will find that

$2^{n} \equiv 2^{n+6}$

when summing the digits of the result of each.

Comment: As the OP stated in a comment, he does not want repeated sums, just the simple sum of the digits of $2^n$. Otherwise, this is a good answer.

Comment: He posted that whilst I was typing (I'm quite slow at latex) and I didn't see his comment. Should I delete my post?

Comment: That's up to you. I just upvoted your answer.

Comment: I'll leave it then. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

$2^n$ has $d$ digits if and only if $10^{d-1} \leq 2^n < 10^d$. Taking $\ln$ gives $(d-1) \ln 10 \leq n\ln 2 <d \ln 10$ which gives $d-1 \leq n \frac{\ln 2}{\ln 10} < d$, showing that $d-1$ is equal to the integer part (so-called *floor*) of $n\frac{\ln 2}{\ln 10}$. The number of digits of $2^n$ is therefore equal to one plus the integer part of $n\frac{\ln 2}{\ln 10}$. This is a closed formula, by the way.

Now, how to calculate the sum $S = \sum_{i=0}^d a_i$ of digits of $2^n$ if we write if $2^n = \sum_{i=0}^d a_i 10^i$, with $0\leq a_i < 10$ ?

Consider $2^n / 10^d = \sum_{i=0}^d a_i 10^i / 10^d = a_d + \sum_{i=0}^{d-1} a_i 10^{i-d}$. Then $a_d$ is the integer part of $2^n / 10^d $. Can we iterate this to get all $a_i$'s ? Yes we can : what do we get if we take the integer part of $2^n / 10^{d-1}$ this time ? We get $10 a_d + a_{d-1}$ and we know $a_d$, so that if I note $F$ the integer part function, I have $a_{d-1} = F(2^n / 10^{d-1}) - 10 F(2^n / 10^{d})$.

You can trivially see that $F( 2^n / 10^{d-2})$ is but $100 a_d + 10 a_{d-1} + a_{d-2}$. Which gives us $a_{d-2} = F( 2^n / 10^{d-2}) - 10 ( F(2^n / 10^{d-1}) - 10 F(2^n / 10^{d})) - 100 F( 2^n / 10^{d})$ which you can simplify as $a_{d-2} = F( 2^n / 10^{d-2}) - 10 F(2^n / 10^{d-1})$.

More generally $a_{d-i} = F( 2^n / 10^{d-i}) - 10 F(2^n / 10^{d-i+1})$. And from this you get easily $S$ by summing all the $a_{d-i}$'s.

Of course, this method is not proper to $2^n$ and works with any integer instead of it.

Comment: Sum of digits, not number of digits.

Comment: It will work the same, let me update.

Comment: No it won't!${}$

Comment: It will. And it does.

Comment: $a_d$ is not the integer part of $2^n/10^d$. For instance , the integer part of $16384/100$ is $163$, not $3$.

Comment: Yes, but the integer part of $16384/10000 = 1.6384$ is $1$.

Comment: Well, you edited out the obvious error since I posted my comment! In any case, your new "algorithm" is completely different from your initial proposal: it requires integer-arithmetic computation of $2^n$ in base $10$. It simply takes the obvious algorithm and makes it harder to understand.

Comment: I'm really sorry but it gives closed formula for computation of digits which are needed to know the sum, and it tells you exactly when to stop. In eveything writting as of now in this question page, I don't see anything related to an algorithm to calculate the digits, except what I precisely gave - after error indeed. (I don't see any "obvious algorithm" stated anywhere, btw, so if it's obvious, please had it stated before.) As I told, it will work, and it worked. It's just that cycling and texting is hard. ;-)

Comment: And please don't tell me that the "obvious algorithm" consists in calculating the power of $2$ and summing its digits, because that's the question.

Comment: The obvious algorithm is to start with $1$ and double it $n$ times in base $10$. That gives you all the digits, and is $O(n^2)$. Your algorithm is (presumably) to start with $2^n$ in binary, and to divide it by $10$ as often as necessary. That gives you all the digits, and is $O(n^2)$. See my answer for a faster way.

Comment: I never saw anywhere here that the computation of $2^n$ was part of the task. OP want's a formula, I give one, point. Cheers and bye.