# Slopes of regression lines of sum of digits of specific values

Tags: analysis, summation, linear-regression

Why and how mathematically can it be proved ?

---

From my analysis :

X-axis will be $n$ value.
Y-axis will be the n-th sum of digits of $x^n$ form.

On the current image, where $x=2$, the black line is a regression line with $a$ slope.

[image]

If we get slopes $a$ for $x \in (1, 2, \dots, 100)$, then the curve looks:
[image]

From further analysis, it seems that this curve is $\log(x) * \alpha$ where $\alpha$ is some constant.

Answer (score 1):

The number of digits of $2^n$ in base $10$ is $\lceil n \log_{10}2\rceil  \approx 0.30103 n$ for $n \gt 1$.  When $n$ is large you expect the average digit to be $4.5$.  The first few and the last few may not be evenly distributed, but for large $n$ the effect will be negligible so we expect the sum of digits of $2^n$ to be about $1.3546n$

Comment: [+1] Good answer. I went through an ancient answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1101502/305862) that looks strange...

Comment: @JeanMarie:  that answer is talking about how to get the exact value quickly.  For this purpose an approximate answer is fine because we just want the slope of the fitted line.